# Loop through LI's in one order, then go back another order - while fading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve a similar effect of that on the UrbanAirship.com, while providing a longer fade transition. I have achieved a one way fade using multiple UL's, with hidden LI's underneath them, and using the fade effect. I've achieved this with the Cycle2 JQUERY plugin, but I've also achieved it using some custom InOut code. I've been able to get a data-speed attribute I've assigned to the LI's to try and get the fade to go back across the main LI's, but after one loop they get screwy.

Here's the HTML:

```
    <ul class="row" id="community-rotator">
<li>
    <ul class="logos-1">
        <li data-speed="5000"><img src="Leukemia&LymphomaSociety.png"></li>
        <li data-speed="10000"><img src="BoysAndGirlsClub.png"></li>
        <li data-speed="2000"><img src="SusanKomenPhoenix.png"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <ul class="logos-2">
        <li data-speed="6000"><img src="AmericanCancer.png"></li>
        <li data-speed="8000"><img src="NotreDamePrep.png"></li>
        <li data-speed="4000"><img src="ChronsFoundation.png"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <ul class="logos-3">
        <li data-speed="7000"><img src="RonaldMcDonaldHouse.png"></li>
        <li data-speed="6000"><img src="SusanKomenFlorida.png"></li>
        <li data-speed="6000"><img src="DMHS.png"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <ul  class="logos-4">
        <li data-speed="8000"><img src="phoenixchildrens.png"></li>
        <li data-speed="4000"><img src="MIKID.png"></li>
        <li data-speed="8000"><img src="RonanThompsonFoundation.png"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <ul  class="logos-5">
        <li data-speed="9000"><img src="100club.png"></li>
        <li data-speed="2000"><img src="ASU.png"></li>
        <li data-speed="10000"><img src="SunshineAcres.png"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And here's the hackedy Javascript:

```
        function InOut( elem ) 
{
    var delaySpeed = elem.data('speed')
    elem.delay()
    .fadeIn(500)
    .delay(delaySpeed )
    .fadeOut(
        500,
        function(){
            if(elem.next().length > 0)
                {InOut( elem.next() );}
            else
                {InOut( elem.siblings(':first'));}
        }
        );
}

$('.logos-1 li').hide();
InOut( $('.logos-1 li:first'));

$('.logos-2 li').hide();
InOut( $('.logos-2 li:first'));

$('.logos-3 li').hide();
InOut( $('.logos-3 li:first'));

$('.logos-4 li').hide();
InOut( $('.logos-4 li:first'));

$('.logos-5 li').hide();
InOut( $('.logos-5 li:first'));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm new to this whole programming thing :)

Thanks!

Comment: If you are trying to duplicate exactly what they did, they used coffeescript and ojp_marquee.  Here is a link to the script https://github.com/dylansm/code_library/blob/master/coffeescript/ojp_marquee.js

Comment: Obviously slight more complicated than I had originally thought it would be. Thanks for the info, I'll take a look through and see if I can't replicate it without copying it entirely. Thanks :)

Comment: There are plenty of jquery plugins that do sliders, and many with fade. I would look into using one of them. Alternatively if you are just beginning, I would suggest that you look into using a framework that already has a lot of the functionality you will be needed baked in.  Two good ones to start with are Twitter-Bootstrap and Zurb-Foundation, IMO Bootstrap 3 at http://getbootstrap.com/ would be your best bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than re-invent the wheel, you might want to take a look at one of the many jquery sliders out there.  Alternatively you could look into a JS and CSS framework that has this type of stuff fleshed out already. 
Here is one example I found.

http://www.simplefadeslideshow.com/